# UITextView height changes to scrollable after adding Line Break

Tags: swift

I am trying to set the height of a UITextview and all works well until I try to format the text.

An example might be "/n" or using a line break with the Swift Multiline String Literals.

After that the Textview becomes scrollable with some sort of max height value.

Does formatting the text destroy the "self.overViewTxt.contentSize.height"?

Thanks.

```
@IBOutlet weak var overViewTxt: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var overviewTxtHC: NSLayoutConstraint!

overViewTxt.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, \n sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."

overviewTxtHC.constant = self.overViewTxt.contentSize.height
```

or

```
overViewTxt.text = """
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat\n  non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    """
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITextView` has a unique property of calculating height automatically. You DON'T need to take the `IBOutlet` of constraint or do not give any fix HEIGHT constraint, rather than you need to disable it's scrolling property and then assign any text it will be automatically became of it's size.

Note: Make sure you give proper constraints, i.e., top, bottom, leading & trailing.

Comment: damn, that was way to simple.  I was obviously overthinking it. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to update frame instead of using constraint:

```
overViewTxt.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, \n sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."

let overviewTxtHCSize = overviewTxtHC.intrinsicContentSize
overviewTxtHC.bounds.size = overviewTxtHCSize
```